# I've set up Apache, but I can't write to the '/var/www' folder

Tags: permissions, apache-http-server, fedora-14

I've set up Fedora 14 with Apache, MySQL and PHP for my own homepage on a "server" (read: old hardware scrapped together).

I'm logged in with my user, but I have no rights on `/var/www/html`.

How do I change this, so that I can save my files to this folder? Maybe change the permissions or redirect the folder to my home folder?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The www folder is created by most distributions during the apache setup process. As the setup process is run by root, the www folder is owned by root. Use `ls -al` in `/var` to look at it's permissions.

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  4096 May  2 11:34 www
```

`chmod` and `chown` are GNU coreutils that you can use to modify the permissions of unix directories.

Use `chown` to change the owner and group of `/var/www/html/` to your user and group, e.g.

```
sudo chown -R jason:jason /var/www/html/
```

As you're likely to start putting PHP scripts in here, you'll then need to use `chmod` to make sure the apache user (in most cases `www-data`) is allowed to execute them.

Try and understand [how Unix permissions work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions) before proceeding any further as it will save you some time down the line. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

As root, run `chown yourusername /var/www/html`. This will assign it to your user. Alternatively, you could set up Apache to use some directory inside your home directory as "DocumentRoot". (see `/etc/apache`, `/etc/httpd` or similar).

Most Apache installations are also set up to link your `$HOME/public_html/` to `http://server/~username`.

Both approaches have some limitations in that you have to give far-reaching permissions to the files, so you can edit them and the webserver can read them (and if you use [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), edit them in some cases, should this be necessary). For this reason, it might be better to copy files to `/var/www/html` and assign them to the web server user.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a better idea to create a separate *user:group* for the httpd service; *apache:apache* is already created during my httpd installation on my [Fedora 19](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Fedora_releases#Fedora_19) system.

Then, you can change the *owner:group* and other permissions to *apache:apache*, while adding your username to the group apache by executing `gpasswd -a myUsername1 apache`.

If [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) is installed, make sure you follow the guidelines and rules about working with the apache-server under a SELinux-configured system.