# Can't write to /var/www/html

Tags: linux, permissions, apache-http-server

(I'll link to other answers that I read next)
I've installed LAMP stack, and I'm trying to put files in /var/www/html

```
 nati@nati-pc:/var/www/html$ touch example
 touch: cannot touch 'example': Permission denied
```

I changed the permissions to `www` folder

```
 nati@nati-pc:/var$ ls -al
 drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data www-data 4096 Oct 29 20:40 www
```

also to `html`:

```
 nati@nati-pc:/var/www$ ls -al
 drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Oct 29 20:40 html
```

I added my self to `www-data` group:

```
 nati@nati-pc:/var/www$ awk -F':' '/www-data/{print $4}' /etc/group
 nati
```

As you can see the group permissions of www & html are 7 and I'm in the group so I don't understand why can't I write to the folder.

I followed this answer ([https://superuser.com/questions/278446/ive-set-up-apache-but-i-cant-write-to-the-var-www-folder#*=*](https://superuser.com/questions/278446/ive-set-up-apache-but-i-cant-write-to-the-var-www-folder#_=_))

Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to Shimi I checked with `id` command if the group includes me and it didn't so I needed to log in using `sudo su nati` and then the `id` command showed me that I'm in the group and since then I can edit the files.